# Use Net::LDAP with a /etc/*.conf ldap text editable configuration file

Tags: perl, unix, ldap

In order to list the users which finally have access to one service which is authenticated through **pam.d**, I would like to **connect to my LDAP (perl Net::LDAP) using a conf file** and not by mentioning ldap-ipaddress, port, password or anything except the name of the conf file which is used in `/etc/pam.d/myservice`, let us name this `/etc/ldap.myservice.conf`.

Is there a open-source or free software project which aim at using perl module `Net::LDAP` with a conf file for pam.d module instead of mentioning connection credentials?  Or may be I have to parse myself this file?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use Net::LDAP ; # dreamed late at night
my $connection = new Net::LDAP( '/etc/myservice.ldap.conf' ) ; 
(...)
```

I browsed the Internet and found nothing. I feel that this feature could  give more versatility and integration to most of systems.